# MySQL Auto Insert Record Into TableB when TableA record is created

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql, relational-database

I have two tables. msUser and msUserChar. I have created a relationship between msUser and msUserChar where the PK in msUser is a FK in msUserChar

What I need, is when a record is inserted into msUser, a record is also created in msUserChar where it's FK is the PK from msUser.

I have tried using constraints, update cascade and various other relationship methods. I am aware, I can use the Last_Insert_Id method, or use transactional mysql and only commit when both records have been created. I am wondering however, if there is a way to do this in a relationship manner.

Essentially, ever user must have a character. So when the user table is inserted with a record, a related record is created in the user character table.

as requested, here are the tables described:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| _msId     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| msUser    | varchar(25)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msPass    | varchar(30)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msSecret  | varchar(30)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msEmail   | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msAccType | int(2)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msLastLog | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| _msCharUserID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| _msId         | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| _msCharID     | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| msChar_1      | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| msChar_2      | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| msChar_3      | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: please describe both of your table columns

Comment: create trigger for event after insert on first table

Comment: @MySQLRockstar, please see the updated question. @M khalid Junaid, I know I can use triggers, but surly, there is a better way by utilising the relationship built into mysql?

Comment: Why is trigger a "worse" way? This is exactly what triggers are all about. do these whenever i do something on a table.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut I'm not saying it's a worse way, I just assumed if mysql had built in relational features, this would be included

Comment: Well mysql has no built-in features to do that. You have to write your own as a trigger or sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL it is impossible with one query as `INSERT` can only insert data to one table at once. So if you do not want to use `TRIGGERS`, then you may try this

1. Create a stored procedure which will execute 2 INSERT statements
2. Wrap those 2 INSERTS in a transaction to ensure both queries are successful.

Comment: What is the best method to use? SP, TSQ, Trigger...?

Comment: It depends based on usage in application. SP can return values, Triggers cannot. You can CALL SP but cannot CALL trigger, it executes automatically based on event limited to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

Comment: Also trigger code will execute once for every row affected by a DML statement, hence the trigger can easily become the most significant factor in DML performance. Checkout [restriction on stored routines and triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

Comment: That's great information thanks, I guess the best way to move forward would be to write a SP as this will only occur when the user creates an account, and no other time :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use trigger

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER TrgMsUser BEFORE INSERT ON msUser 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO msUserChar SET _msId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```